# What could be the function of this op-amp circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is a part of a larger circuit; I don't understand what these op-amps do. The input comes from a current transducer that outputs a proportional voltage.

[image]

Comment: Partial circuits are usually unhelpful unless you know what the circuit does then, you don't need to ask so, post the full circuit.

Comment: Ground symbols pointing everywhere except downwards is also confusing.

Comment: Where does T2's gate go?

Comment: Assume that T2 is on at all times. @Andyaka The whole board has many functions, but this particular function of the circuit is presented in its entirety.

Comment: Not without you writing that T2 is on all the time into your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a full wave rectifier.

Feedback for positive inputs is via the 2nd opamp; for negative it is via the diode.

Comment: Thanks! What use is the 100pf C16 capacitor, across the first op-amp output and inverting input?

Comment: Something to control stability or slew rates at the zero crossings. At 60 Hz the circuit spends a relatively long time there and you could have oscillations in the loop